# Errors on startup with Logback and MySQL. Causes dialect error

Tags: java, mysql, spring, logback

I have logback-spring.xml with next content:

```xml
    <springProperty name="url" source="spring.datasource.url"/>
    <springProperty name="username" source="spring.datasource.username"/>
    <springProperty name="password" source="spring.datasource.password"/>

    <appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
        <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
            <driverClass>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
            <url>${url}</url>
            <user>${username}</user>
            <password>${password}</password>
        </connectionSource>
    </appender>

    <logger name="dbLogger" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="DB"/>
    </logger>
```

I got an error on application startup:

```xml
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@36:16 - RuntimeException in Action for tag [appender] java.lang.IllegalStateException:
DBAppender cannot function if the JDBC driver does not support getGeneratedKeys method *and* without a specific SQL dialect
```

I tried to add `<sqlDialect class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.dialect.MySQLDialect" />` or/and change `<driverClass>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>` to `<driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>` (old version), but it didn't help.

With MySQLDialect I have error with next content:

```xml
no applicable action for [driverClass], current ElementPath is [[configuration][appender][connectionSource][driverClass]]
```

**OR**

```xml
no applicable action for [driverClass], current ElementPath is [[configuration][appender][driverClass]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JDBC 3.0 or higher and mySQL 5.0.8  or higher Then SQLDialect is not required it will be provided by logback itself.

Mostly seems like not in your case then try these things-
Then you must add SQL dialect **( As you already added )** 
After search i found this -

Adding this jar may help  [Reference] ([logback and mysql Connections could not be acquired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993018/logback-and-mysql-connections-could-not-be-acquired))

```
logback-examples-1.0.0.jar
```

Alternatively

Try this to add a dialect  [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43536302/set-sqldialect-to-logback-db-appender-programmatically)

Comment: I think my problem is that the configuration does not have time to get the values for connecting to the DB.  I get values from Azure KeyVault and, perhaps, they come later than the logback starts.